# When should I return a pointer to an array vs setting values in an existing array

Tags: c++

When is it better to have a function return a pointer to an array, like this:

```
int * foo(int n) {
    int * output = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        output[i] = i;
    }
    return output;    
}

int main() {
    int * arr = foo(10);
    return 0;
}
```

vs having the function not return anything but just set values of an array given in the parameters, like this:

```
void foo(int n, int output[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        output[i] = i;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[10];
    foo(10, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

For example, I have a function that generates prime numbers, and I would like to return them as an array. Should I use the first option and return a pointer to the array, or pass an array into the function and put the values in that?

Comment: Even better, return a `std::vector<int>` by value.

Comment: @Thomas Briggs There is no relation between these two different approaches. So there is nothing to compare.

Comment: It's better to avoid anything that requires calling `new` or `delete[]` if you can, because they are error-prone to use and tend to lead to crashing and/or memory-leaking programs unless handled very carefully.  Therefore between the two options, option 2 is better (although in C++ `std::vector<int>` is better still, as @CoryKramer pointed out)

Comment: Well I have a function that generates a given amount of primes numbers and outputs an array with them all in, which way would be considered better, to pass an array into the function and put the prime numbers in that array or to return an pointer to an array that the function created because they seem to have the same outcome except one is an actual array where is one is a pointer, and the actual array seems to be better than way it is easy to find the size of it.

Comment: I would reword the question as when to use the first approach versus when to use the second. And limit it to either C. In C++ the answer will probably be "use `std::vector`"

Comment: In C++, neither approach is idiomatic. In C, it depends on the specific circumstances (i.e. the use case for the function).

Comment: C or C++ ? The question is tagged C, but your code is C++

Comment: @Jabberwocky  The language tag toggles every minute :-)

Comment: It was meant to be c++

Comment: @ThomasBriggs It _is_ C++. `new` doesn't exist in C.

Comment: @ThomasBriggs The expected way of solving this problem is to simply return a `std::vector<int>` and forget that dynamically allocating arrays even exists. It's easier for you to write, it's easier for the function's user to use and it's safer for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When sould I return a pointer to an array

When you have a function that creates an array - but there are better ways to do it in C++ than to return a raw pointer to the memory (since those pointers are easy to forget about so you get memory leaks etc). You can for example use the dynamic array-like `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> foo(size_t n) {
    std::vector<int> output(n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        output[i] = i;
    return output;
}

std::vector<int> arr = foo(10);
std::cout << arr.size() << "\n";
std::cout << arr[9] << "\n";
```

> vs setting values in an existing array

When you already have an array that you want to use as input and you want to modify it.

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& inout) { 
    for(int& val : inout)
        val += 10;                   // add 10 to every element
}
```